# The project I'm working on cuts off after the 5th page when I build it

Tags: texstudio

I am working on a project in texstudio, and my pdf cuts off after the 5th page. Anyone know why this could be?

Thanks, 
John

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\tikzset{
    ->, % makes the edges directed
    %>=stealth’, % makes the arrow heads bold
    node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
    initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

    \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
        \centering % centers the figure
            \item[1.4]
        \item[e] 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
        \node[state,right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
        \draw 
        (q1) edge[bend right, below] node{b} (q3)
        (q1) edge[above] node{a} (q2)
        (q2) edge[loop above] node{a,b} (q2)
        (q3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (q3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ starts with an $a\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial, accepting] (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[state,right of=s2] (s3) {$s_3$};
        \draw 
        (s1) edge[loop below] node{a} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{b} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop below] node{a} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{b} (s3)
        (s3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (s3);
        \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has at most one $b\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label2}   
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (s1q1) {$s_1, q_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=s1q1] (s1q2) {$s_1, q_2$};
        \node[state, below of=s1q1] (s2q3) {$s_2, q_3$};
        \node[state, accepting,below of=s1q2] (s2q2) {$s_2, q_2$};
        \node[state, below of=s2q3] (s3q3) {$s_3, q_3$};
        \node[state, below of=s2q2] (s3q2) {$s_3, q_2$};

        \draw 
        (s1q1) edge[above] node{a} (s1q2)
        (s1q1) edge[right] node{b} (s2q3)
        (s1q2) edge[loop above] node{a} (s1q2)
        (s1q2) edge[right] node{b} (s2q2)
        (s2q3) edge[loop left] node{a} (s2q3)
        (s2q3) edge[left] node{b} (s3q3)
        (s3q3) edge[loop left] node{a, b} (s3q3)
        (s2q2) edge[loop left] node{a} (s2q2)
        (s2q2) edge[left] node{b} (s3q2)
        (s3q2) edge[loop left] node{a, b} (s3q2);
        \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);  
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ starts with an $a$ and $w$ has at most one $b\}$};
        \label{fig:my_label23}
        where ($s_3$, $q_1$), ($s_2$, $q_1$), and ($s_1$, $q_3$) have been optimized out.
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
        \centering % centers the figure
        \item[1.4] 
        \item[f.]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_{even}$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_{odd}$};
        \draw 
        (q1) edge[bend left, above] node{a} (q2)
        (q1) edge[loop above] node{b} (q1)
        (q2) edge[bend left, below] node{a} (q1)
        (q2) edge[loop above] node{b} (q2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has an odd number of $a$'s$\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label5}   
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
        \draw 
        (s1) edge[loop above] node{$a$} (s1)
        (s1) edge[bend left, above] node{$b$} (s2)
        (s2) edge[bend left, below] node{$a$} (s1)
        (s2) edge[loop above] node{$b$} (s2);
        \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ ends with $b\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label4}   
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (s1qe) {$s_1, q_{even}$};
        \node[state, right of=s1qe] (s2qe) {$s_2, q_{even}$};
        \node[state, below of=s1qe] (s1qo) {$s_1, q_{odd}$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=s1qo] (s2qo) {$s_2, q_{odd}$};
        \draw 
        (s1qe) edge[bend left, left] node{$a$} (s1qo)
        (s1qe) edge[bend left, above] node{$b$} (s2qe)
        (s2qe) edge[bend left, below] node{$a$} (s1qo)
        (s2qe) edge[loop above] node{$b$} (s2qe)
        (s1qo) edge[bend left, left] node{$a$} (s1qe)
        (s1qo) edge[bend right, below] node{$b$} (s2qo)
        (s2qo) edge[bend right, right] node{$a$} (s1qe)
        (s2qo) edge[bend right, right] node{$b$} (s2qe);
        \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has an odd number of $a$'s and ends with a $b\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label7}   
    \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
    \centering % centers the figure
    \item[1.4] 
    \item[g.]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_{even}$};
    \node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_{odd}$};
    \draw 
    (q1) edge[bend left, above] node{a} (q2)
    (q1) edge[loop above] node{b} (q1)
    (q2) edge[bend left, below] node{a} (q1)
    (q2) edge[loop above] node{b} (q2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has an odd number of $a$'s$\}$}
    \label{fig:my_labela}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, initial, accepting] (se) {$s_{even}$};
    \node[state, right of=se] (so) {$s_{odd}$};
    \draw 
    (se) edge[bend left, above] node{$a, b$} (so)
    (so) edge[bend left, above] node{$a, b$} (se);
    \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$\{w$: $w$ an even length $\}$}
    \label{fig:my_label10}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, initial] (seqe) {$s_{even}, q_{even}$};
    \node[state, right of=seqe] (soqo) {$s_{odd}, q_{odd}$};
    \node[state, below of=seqe] (soqe) {$s_{odd}, q_{even}$};
    \node[state, accepting, right of=soqe] (seqo) {$s_{even}, q_{odd}$};
    \draw 
    (seqe) edge[bend left, above] node{$a$} (soqo)
    (seqe) edge[bend left, left] node{$b$} (soqe)
    (soqe) edge[bend left, above] node{$a$} (seqo)
    (soqe) edge[bend left, left] node{$b$} (seqe)
    (soqo) edge[bend left, below] node{$a$} (seqe)
    (soqo) edge[bend left, left] node{$b$} (seqo)
    (seqo) edge[bend left, below] node{$a$} (soqe)
    (s2qo) edge[bend left, left] node{$b$} (soqo);
    \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has an odd number of $a$'s and ends with a $b\}$}
    \label{fig:my_labelo}   
\end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
        \centering % centers the figure
        \item[1.5] 
        \item[c] 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
        \node[state, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
        \draw 
        (q1) edge[above] node{a} (q2)
        (q1) edge[loop above] node{b} (q1)
        (q2) edge[loop above] node{a} (q2)
        (q2) edge[above] node{b} (q3)
        (q3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (q3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ contains $ab\}$}
        \label{fig:my_labeltable}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[state, right of=s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=s2] (s3) {$s_3$};
        \draw 
        (s1) edge[loop above] node{a} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{b} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{a} (s3)
        (s2) edge[loop above] node{b} (s2)
        (s3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (s3);
        \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ contains $ba\}$}
        \label{fig:my_labelol}  
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1s1) {$q_1, s_1$};
        \node[state, right of=q1s1] (q1s2) {$q_1, s_2$};
        \node[state, below of=s1q1] (q2s2) {$q_2, s_2$};
        \node[state, below of=q1s2] (q2s3) {$q_2, s_3$};
        \node[state, below of=q2s2] (q3s2) {$q_3, s_2$};
        \node[state, accepting, below of=q2s3] (q3s3) {$q_3, s_2$};

        \draw 
        (q1s1) edge[left] node{a} (q2s2)
        (q1s1) edge[above] node{b} (q1s2)
        (q1s2) edge[right] node{a} (q2s3)
        (q1s2) edge[right] node{b} (q2s2)
        (q2s2) edge[above] node{a} (q2s3)
        (q2s2) edge[right] node{b} (q3s2)
        (q2s3) edge[loop right] node{a} (q2s3)
        (q2s3) edge[right] node{b} (q3s3)
        (q3s2) edge[below] node{a} (q3s3)
        (q3s2) edge[loop below] node{b} (q3s2)
        (q3s3) edge[loop below] node{a, b} (q3s3);
        \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);  
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ contains $ab$ and $ba\}$};
        \label{fig:my_labelp}
        where ($q_1$, $s_3$), ($q_2$, $s_1$), and ($q_3$, $s_1$) have been optimized out.
    %\end{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, accepting,initial] (q1s1) {$q_1, s_1$};
    \node[state, accepting,right of=q1s1] (q1s2) {$q_1, s_2$};
    \node[state, accepting,below of=s1q1] (q2s2) {$q_2, s_2$};
    \node[state, accepting,below of=q1s2] (q2s3) {$q_2, s_3$};
    \node[state, accepting,below of=q2s2] (q3s2) {$q_3, s_2$};
    \node[state,  below of=q2s3] (q3s3) {$q_3, s_2$};

    \draw 
    (q1s1) edge[left] node{a} (q2s2)
    (q1s1) edge[above] node{b} (q1s2)
    (q1s2) edge[right] node{a} (q2s3)
    (q1s2) edge[right] node{b} (q2s2)
    (q2s2) edge[above] node{a} (q2s3)
    (q2s2) edge[right] node{b} (q3s2)
    (q2s3) edge[loop right] node{a} (q2s3)
    (q2s3) edge[right] node{b} (q3s3)
    (q3s2) edge[below] node{a} (q3s3)
    (q3s2) edge[loop below] node{b} (q3s2)
    (q3s3) edge[loop below] node{a, b} (q3s3);
    \path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$\{w$: $w$ does not contain $ab$ nor $ba\}$};
    \label{fig:my_labelhp}
    where ($q_1$, $s_3$), ($q_2$, $s_1$), and ($q_3$, $s_1$) have been optimized out.
\end{figure}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you look at the log file, you will see two warnings: `Float too large for page`. One is too big by 264 pt. which is more than 3 inches. So split the larger floats into smaller ones.

Comment: A figure can not break over pages. And the \item in the figure doesn't make sense (it is a wonder that it works.)

Comment: Ulrike, the \item in the figures corresponds to the text I am working out of. But they are coming out wired. Do you know how to correct this?

Comment: what is the intention of `\begin{enumerate}

    \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
        \centering % centers the figure
            \item[1.4]`     inside the figure you have floating `\item` that are not in a list, and the outer `enumerate` has no items????

Comment: we can't say how to correct the errors if you give no indication of the intended output. Certain;y you should delete the `\item` elements from the figure.

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear. I am trying to indicate which textbook problem each figure correlates to. I guess I was hoping for the problem numbers in the upper lefthand corners of the figures.